# Javascript Font scaling code from body to div / element

Tags: javascript

I found some code which will scale some text when the browser window is resized and it seems to work well.

Here is the code:

```
   document.body.setScaledFont = function (f) {
       var s = this.offsetWidth,
           fs = s * f;
       this.style.fontSize = fs + '%';
       return this
   };

   document.body.setScaledFont(0.35);
   window.onresize = function () {
       document.body.setScaledFont(0.35);
   }
```

My question is:

How can I modify this code so the text scales when a specified div is scaled instead?

**Updated code from suggested answer by @Deano**. This code scales only when the browser is resized.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">



    #window {
        border:1px dashed #ccc;
         overflow: hidden;
         resize: both;
         text-align: center;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="window">Scale the window</div>




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#window').mouseup( function() {

        document.getElementById('window').setScaledFont = function (f) {
            var s = this.offsetWidth,
            fs = s * f;
            this.style.fontSize = fs + '%';
            return this
        };

           document.getElementById('window').setScaledFont(0.35);
           window.onresize = function () {
           document.getElementById('window').setScaledFont(0.35);
        }

      });

    });



  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body` targets the entire body, if you want to target a specific element, use `Id` or `class`.

```js
   document.getElementById('window').setScaledFont = function (f) {
   var s = this.offsetWidth,
       fs = s * f;
   this.style.fontSize = fs + '%';
   return this
   };

   document.getElementById('window').setScaledFont(0.35);
   window.onresize = function () {
   document.getElementById('window').setScaledFont(0.35);
   }
```

```css
div {
    font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="window">Scale the window</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amlife/cnfb480j/)

**Update** Since the question requirement has changed :-/

You will need to use a libary like mimetic.js [DEMO](http://envidia.co.uk/mimetic/examples/style-on-zoom/)

Comment: I couldnt get it to scale when the div is resized. Please see full code on edited bottom part of the question above

Comment: I have added a JSfiddle link :)

Comment: Yes Ive seen but it wont scale on div resize...Please see my edited question full code so you know what I mean

Comment: Try to make the div resiable by adding this: overflow: hidden;
         resize: both; ...then try it..You'll see what I mean

Comment: PS: My question never changed...My question was: "How can I modify this code so the text scales when a specified div is scaled instead?"